# Random Variable Problem with unrestricted Parameters Worded Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

I have no idea how to go about solving (a) -> (c)

- For (a) Is $k=0.2$, because $\frac{k}{1-0.8}=1$
- Hence, $P(Z=z) = 0.2(0.8)^x$

But How do we determine the mean or variance with unrestricted z values.

Comment: No definition in the pages just before the one you included?

Comment: -1 for posting a picture instead of a formatted text

Answer (score 1):

(1)- yes.

(2)- in the general case

$\begin{align}
\because \sum_{x=0}^\infty p (1-p)^x &= \frac{p}{1-(1-p)} & \forall |p|< 1:\text{ the series converges} 
\\ & = 1
\\[2ex]
 \therefore P(X=x) &= p (1-p)^x \;:\; x\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\} & \text{is a probability mass function}
\\[2ex] \text{Then use the following:}
\\[2ex]
 \mathsf{Var}[X] & := \mathsf{E}[X^2]-\mathsf{E}[X]\;^2 & \text{definition of variance}
\\[2ex]
 \mathsf{E}[X] &= p \sum_{x=0}^\infty x(1-p)^x & \text{the expectation of }X
\\[1ex]
 \mathsf{E}[X^2] & = p\sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2(1-p)^x & \text{the expectation of }X^2
\\[2ex]
\therefore \ldots
\end{align}$

Comment: I don't know how to work with the sum function when subtracting E[X] from E[X^2]

Comment: @confused $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k r^k \mathop{=}_{|r|<1} \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}\quad,\quad \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k^2 r^k  \mathop{=}_{|r|<1}\frac{r(r+1)}{(1-r)^3}$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint for the expectation value*

$E(Z)=\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}k\cdot z\cdot 0.8^z$

index shift

$\sum_{z=1}^{\infty} k\cdot (z-1)\cdot \frac{0.8^z}{0.8}=\sum_{z=1}^{\infty}k\cdot z\cdot \frac{0.8^z}{0.8}- \sum_{z=1}^{\infty} k\cdot \frac{0.8^z}{0.8}$

$\sum_{z=1}^{\infty} k\cdot z\cdot \frac{0.8^z}{0.8}=\sum_{z=0}^{\infty} k\cdot z\cdot \frac{0.8^z}{0.8}=\frac{1}{0.8} E(Z)$

$\sum_{z=1}^{\infty} k\cdot  \frac{0.8^z}{0.8}=k\cdot \sum_{z=0}^{\infty} 0.8^z$

$E(Z)=\frac{1}{0.8} E(Z)-k\cdot \sum_{z=0}^{\infty} 0.8^z$

This equation can be solved for $E(Z)$.